# Why can't I return data from an API service in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm upgrading from Ionic 3 to 4 and keep encountering problems with my API services. In this particular instance I'm trying to retrieve a user's tickets so that I may list them.

Unfortunately, every time I do this I get the 'whoops' error message, even if the tickets are successfully fetched from the API. On top of that I can't seem to figure out how to successfully get the tickets returned from the service into my page; I'm currently getting a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error.

On top of that, the `data` is now coming back as `data: [object Object],[object Object]`

### ticket.service

```
getSubmittedTickets() {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('username', this.username);
    body.append('password', this.password);
    this.http
        .post(this.apiService.url, body)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log('data: ' + data);
            return data;
        }, error => {
            console.log('whoops');
        });
}
```

### ticket.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getSubmittedTickets();
}

getSubmittedTickets() {
    this.ticketService.getSubmittedTickets()
    .then(data => {
        this.tickets = data;
        console.log('tickets: '+this.tickets);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service should return an Observable

```
getSubmittedTickets() {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('username', this.username);
    body.append('password', this.password);
    return this.http.post(this.apiService.url, body);      
}
```

and the component calls the method from the service and then subscribe to the returned value

```
getSubmittedTickets() {
    this.ticketService.getSubmittedTickets()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.tickets = data;
        console.log('tickets: '+this.tickets);
    });
}
```

Comment: That actually worked, but `console.log('tickets: '+this.tickets);` is returning `tickets: [object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: And what is the problem with the console.log? It is probably printing (logging) an array of objects. Or it is a string?

Comment: It's printing `tickets: [object Object],[object Object]` instead of the array

Answer (score 0):

The method name in your service is `getTickets()`. But in your TS file, you have used `getSubmittedTickets()`.

The code in your TS file should be:

```
getSubmittedTickets() {
    this.ticketService.getTickets()
    .then(data => {
        this.tickets = data;
        console.log('tickets: '+this.tickets);
    });
}
```

Comment: That was just a typo when creating this post; it's correct in the service.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert the `observable` to `promise` with [toPromise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)

```
getSubmittedTickets() {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('username', this.username);
    body.append('password', this.password);
    return this.http
        .post(this.apiService.url, body)
        .toPromise()
}
```

Comment: Returns `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Object>'`. Switched `subscribe()` to `then()` and received `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`